# Запуск python-скрипта из c++

Tags: python, c++

Есть скрипт, который выполняет генерацию файла. Как его запустить, передав ему аргумент?
Свою ошибку понял. Уточняю, ос Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Просто вызовите из кода функцию system() и передайте ваш скрипт и его параметры

```
system("python myscript.py");
```

Решение конечно не очень красивое, но оно работает

Answer (score 1):

Существует, на мой взгляд, более правильное решение - использование Python/C API
([введение](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html), [документация](http://docs.python.org/c-api/index.html)). Ваша задача решается примерно так:

```
//C code
#include <Python.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    const char* script_path = "./script.py";
    char* py_argv[] = {strdup(script_path), strdup("argument")};
    PySys_SetArgv(2, py_argv);
    PyRun_SimpleFileEx(fopen(script_path, "r"), script_path, 1);
    free(py_argv[0]);
    free(py_argv[1]);
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

=================

```
#script.py
import sys

print sys.argv
```

В результате на консоль будет выведено:

```
['./script.py', 'argument']
```

Answer (score 0):

Если операционная система linux, то [man exec](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=execlp&category=3&russian=0).

UPD: Пример.

```
 #include <unistd.h>  
int main(){  
  std::string path = "/usr/bin/python";  
  std::string script = "/home/user/script.py";  
  std::string arg = "arg";  
  char* a[] = new char*[2];  
  a[0] = script.c_str();  
  a[1] = arg.c_str();
  execvp(path.c_str(), a);
  std::cerr<<"cannot exec"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

UPD2: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/431x4c1w%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
Возможно, это то, что надо.

Comment: В любой ОС есть system

Comment: А Вы знаете, что у Вас в результате получится? Прежний образ процесса замениться новым. Чтобы этого не произошло и родительский процесс сохранился, надо использовать  fork(2).

Answer (score 0):

согласен со всеми выше описанными способами, но лично я предпочел бы использовать boost::python т.к IMHO это самый простой и что не мало важно чистый(код) способ подружить С и Питон..
что касается стандартного Python C/API - это в большинстве случаев каменный век который требует довольно много времени на написание спайки двух языков...

Comment: Си и буст? Несовместимо. Вы ведь имели в виду с++,правда?

Comment: Не слишком ли избыточно прикручивать буст, под виндой, ради одного вызова?..

Comment: Вы ведь имели в виду с++,правда?   - ну да о нем и речь..
ради одного вызова? - возможно и излишне, но кто знает что в голову взбредет после первого удачного теста=)